# is it possible to prevent devServer from being created in isProduction mode?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have two modes, isProduction and isDevelopment, can I put a ternary operator on devServer so that when the isProduction mode, the dev server is not created? or is it meaningless and it will not be created anyway?

```
module.exports = (env, { mode }) => {
  const isProduction = mode === 'production';
  const isDevelopment = mode === 'development';

    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      // https: true,
      historyApiFallback: true, // для чего узнать?
      // proxy: {},
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Checking individually is more readable and clean

Comment: I did it separately, but I couldn't type it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356506/how-to-combine-the-modules-of-the-webpack-through-the-merge-function